# How to unload modules at run-time in mod_perl?

Tags: perl, mod-perl

I have a mod_perl-enable Apache running native (handlers, not Apache::Registry or similar) mod_perl code. As it is known, modules could be compiled and loaded at run-time. For testing purposes, I have a dummy module:

```
package MyPackage;
our $data = '0123456789' x 1000000; # 10 millions characters
1;
```

At run-time I load it and my *httpd* child processes add up 10 megabytes, one by one, after multiple requests. This is fine. This way I can use use ocasionally some memory consuming code, but while it happens rarely, I would like to be able to *unload* the used module after it has done its work.

If you would mention to use the lexical `my` variables, I know that thay are destroyed when the scope is over. So, `our` or package variables are an important factor in this case.

Is it possible to get this at run-time?  if yes, how it could pe done?

Comment: Re "If you would mention to use the lexical my variables, I know that thay are destroyed when the scope is over.", not they're usually not. They are usually emptied (to be later reused), but no memory is freed.

Comment: @ikegami: Probably you are right from a technical point of view, but practically the memory is freed. Maybe the variable and its internal descriptors are kept, which of course should consume some memory, but the memory for the data itself is released.

Comment: No, it's not. It's not freed, and it cannot be used by anything else.  In `{ my $x = "." x 1_000_000; }`, `$x` continues to exist and use 1MB of memory noone else can use past the end of that block.

Comment: @ikegami: Well, I'm sure you are more experienced and you are right, lexicals continue to use memory in your case. But, looking from a *package* perspective, it dosn't work so: `... use MyPkg; ...` and MyPkg `package MyPkg; my $v = '.' x 1e6; 1;`, the memory is released after the module is `use`d (some `sleep`s and memory monitoring reveal this). Anyway, I'm not sure that our discussion complies to site's rules :), but it's interesting and useful. Thanks for your notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core [Symbol](http://perldoc.perl.org/Symbol.html) module contains a function `delete_package` which takes a package name and deletes all of the variables within it.

So in your case:

```
use Symbol 'delete_package';

delete_package 'MyPackage';
```

Comment: @eric-storm : Thank you very much, it seems to be exactly what is needed. While `delete_package()` wipes out everything, is it a simple way to get rid of a specific package variable (logically, something like `destroy_symbol($MyPackage::data)`)?

Comment: If you only want to delete a single variable, then `undef $MyPackage::data` will do the trick.

Comment: @eric-storm : Thanks, it works. It seems the easiest and the most obvious way is the correct one. I was used to write `$var = undef;` forgetting about the fact that `undef` is a function that could take an argument. I still have to learn a lot and be more careful. Thanks again.

Comment: @ArtM, `$var = undef;` does not free any memory, but `undef $var;` does free the string buffer.